# activate menu onclick in bootstrap with codeigniter

Tags: jquery, codeigniter, twitter-bootstrap

I want to activate the menu on click .I am using bootstrap with codeigniter however I have tried a lot but its not working .
Here is my top_menus.php code.

```
 <div class="navbar-wrapper" style="position: absolute;
top: 0;
right: 0;
left: 0;
z-index: 20;
margin-top: 2px;">
<div class="container">
      <div id="menu" class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button class="btn btn-success navbar-toggle" 
                  data-toggle="collapse"
                  data-target=".navbar-collapse"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></span></button>
          <div id="logo">
           <a class="navbar-brand" href="<?php echo "index";?>">blog</a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar" id="mytab">
           <li class="nav active"><a id="signup" href="<?php echo "index/signup";?>">Sign up</a></li>
           <li class="nav"><a id="sign" href="<?php echo "index/signin";?>">Sign In</a></li>
           <li class="nav"><a id="logout" href="<?php echo "index/logout"; ?>">Logout</a></li>
           <li class="nav"><a id="new_post" href="<?php echo "index/posts";?>">new post</a></li>
           <li class="nav"><a id="show_post" href="<?php echo "index/show_post";?>">Show post</a></li>
           <li class="nav"><a id="upload" href="<?php echo "index/upload_form";?>">upload</a></li>
           <li class="nav"><a id="contact" href="<?php echo "index/contact";?>">Contact us</a></li>
         </ul>
       </div>        
     </div>
   </div>
   </div>
```

let suppose I have click on Sign In so it will go to signin.php.
here is the code of signin.php

```
<body class="container" style="padding:40px;">
<?php  $this->load->view('top_menus'); ?>  
<h1> Sign In</h1>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-12">
 <?php

 if($this->session->userdata('username')!=''){
 redirect("index/post");
 }
 echo form_open("index/verifying");
 echo form_input('username','','placeholder="username"');

  ?>
</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-12">
<?php
 echo form_input('password','','placeholder="password"'); 
 echo form_submit('submit','Signin');
 echo form_close();
 ?>
</div>
</div>

   <script src="<?php echo base_url();?>js/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="<?php echo base_url();?>js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="<?php echo base_url();?>js/tabactivation.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){

  $('#sign').click(function(e) {
  var $this = $(this);
  if (!$this.hasClass('active')) {
    $this.addClass('active');
  }
  e.preventDefault();
  });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest method to activate the links are to give specific id to each page through which we will find the menu text and than we will add the css class you could use a separate .js file for activating the menu on click and place the code i am giving you below for only `signin.php` first of all create an id of signin.php e.g

```
<body id="signin">
The rest of the code inside the body.......
</body>
```

Than create java script file and add the following code to it.

```
$("#signin a:contains('Sign In')").parent().addClass('active');
```

so first of all create ids of all pages who is behind the menu click and do the same thing for the rest of the menus and i hope it will work

Comment: Thanks buddy you really made my day but why it was not working with my code I am still wondering

Comment: The code you have provided is fine for tab but not for adding css class to a selector